# Efficient pagination in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pagination

I want to write a stored procedure that does the following:
* Returns the number of records matching a query (to determine the number of pages to show the user)
* Returns another recordset with a certain subset of records from a query for the current page.

From another question I found on StackOverflow (sorry, I lost the link), I found that we do pagination like this:

```
SELECT u.* FROM 
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) as rownum FROM
    (
        [obscenely long select query]
    )
    as t
)
AS u WHERE u.rowNum >= 1 AND u.rowNum <= 20
```

And I can get the number of records returned by [obscenely long select query] by doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRecords from ([obscenely long select query]) AS records
```

I want to get both of these recordsets as effectively as possible.

The only way I can figure how to do it is shoving both of those statements above into one stored procedure. This strikes me as inefficient for a few reasons:

- I have to write out [obscenely long select query] twice, making the solution harder to maintain / change (I *really* want to avoid this, if possible).
- I have to run [obscenely long select query], getting all the possible records (which could be thousands) before cutting it down to a reasonable size for the pagination, only to run it again when getting the count.

Other solutions I've tried:

- Putting [obscenely long select query] in its own stored procedure (this causes syntax errors).

Is there anything that can be done? Should I just suck it up and stick with my current solution, or is there a more elegant way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the `[obscenely long select query]` structure you may be able to use a temp table or table variable:
- fill a temp table with the ids of the matching rows
- count the temp table rows to calculate the number of pages
- to retrieve the results for the caller build a query with the temp table joined with the relevant database tables

Comment: I think this might work. I'll play with temp tables a bit and see what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One soluntion for implementing pagination is:

Your stored procedure will following parameters

```
@PageSize INT,
@PageNumbers INT

;WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT a,
               b,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a) RN
        FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RN  BETWEEN ((@PageNumbers - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@PageNumbers * @PageSize)
```

If you pass @PageNumbers = 1 and @PageSize = 10
Then

```
((@PageNumbers - 1) * @PageSize + 1) = ((1 - 1) * 10 + 1) = 1
and (@PageNumbers * @PageSize) = (1 * 10) = 10
```

Similarly, if @PageNumbers = 2
Then

```
((@PageNumbers - 1) * @PageSize + 1) = ((2 - 1) * 10 + 1) = 11
and (@PageNumbers * @PageSize) = (2 * 10) = 20
```

You can even hard code @PageSize value in your SP.