# Optimizing SQL Server / C# queries and custom paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a database table which looks like this:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](120) NOT NULL,
[QuantitySoldTransaction] [int] NOT NULL,
[TransactionPrice] [float] NOT NULL,
[ItemID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[TransactionDate] [datetime] NULL,
[StateOrProvince] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[CountryName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[TwoCountryCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[UserStoreId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

I have to group by these transactions by these parameters:

- ItemID => Sales by Item
- CountryName => Sales by country
- Transaction date => Sales by date
- Transaction date => Sales by Hours in day
- Transaction date => Sales by day of the week

I have couple of things that I do not fully understand how I should implement it.

For example the data that I show for sales per Item are completely separated on a different view, and sales per country, hour and day of the week are shown on different view as well.

I want to introduce custom paging on the web application so that I can avoid pulling all data at once from the server and thus reduce the load on server.

Each time that I pull out all records, I have to do a group by statement to get the desired data.

For example:

```
ViewBag.Transactions = allStoreItems.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID)
  .Select(pr => new TransactionsTabResults
  {
      Title = pr.Select(x=>x.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
      ItemID = pr.Key.ToString(),
      AveragePrice =  Math.Round(pr.Average(y => y.TransactionPrice), 2),
      TotalSoldItems = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction),
      TotalRevenuePerItem = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(pr.Sum(x => x.TransactionPrice * x.QuantitySoldTransaction)), 2)

  }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalRevenuePerItem).ToList();
```

These would be the sales of each item individually (sales Per Item Id). What is terrible here is that I pull all data at once and then inject it into the user's DOM, which has a horrible performance for the end user and the server.

I figured the only solution would be custom paging which should reduce the load on server.

So my question is: if I create a stored procedure which would do custom paging, but would still do a group by each time a user makes a request, I'm guessing this still has a terrible performance since group by is costly, right?

So my idea here was that I create a table between my:

```
UserStores => New Table Here <= StoreTransactions
```

The new table would contain the grouped by data of each parameter:

1. by date in general (30 days in month), by item id, by date (by 24 hours) and by date again (by 7 days of the week)..

So another question here is: would a many to many table reduce the costliness of the SQL query and thus enable me more smoother paging through records and displaying what I want?

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Comment: Not sure how it fits to your application logic, but have you considered creating indexed views that contain your data grouped on the level you need to fetch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that the given table is analogous to *StoreTransactions* one from your question. To be honest, I don't think a table in the middle as you've suggested would be efficient.

What I would do is, with the presumption that you have a unique clustered index on top of the `IDENTITY` (Id) column, add additional covering nonclustered indexes for the queries that you need. That is, if the index overheads are not an issue. On top of that, I'd write a separate stored procedure for each "grouping" you might need and make that stored procedure's input parameters include *@pageSize* and *@pageNumber*. Then, depending on SQL Server version you have use:

- if your SQL Server is 2012 or newer, use `OFFSET - FETCH` clause ([documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx))
- if your SQL Server is 2008R2 or older, use a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in it to simulate pagination [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24190610/6492765)

My suggestion would be, for an item grouping and SQL Server 2012 or newer version for example:

```
-- setting up my environment
CREATE TABLE dbo.StoreTransactions (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](120) NOT NULL,
    [QuantitySoldTransaction] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionPrice] [float] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StateOrProvince] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [CountryName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [TwoCountryCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [UserStoreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StoreTransactions PRIMARY KEY(Id) -- this makes a unique clustered index on the Id column
);
GO

-- making a covering index for the calculations
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_StoreTransactions_Title_TransactionPrice_QuantitySoldTransaction
    ON dbo.StoreTransactions(Title, TransactionPrice, QuantitySoldTransaction);
GO
-- making an index for the ItemID example
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_StoreTransactions_ItemID
    ON dbo.StoreTransactions(ItemID);
GO

-- stored procedure grouped by ItemID
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ReturnPaginatedDataByItemID
    -- set your defaults
    @pageNumber int = 1,
    @pageSize int = 10
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          MIN(t.Title) AS Title -- this is based on your FirstOrDefault() function
        , t.ItemID
        , AVG(t.TransactionPrice) AS AveragePrice
        , SUM(t.QuantitySoldTransaction) AS TotalSoldItems
        , SUM(t.TransactionPrice*t.QuantitySoldTransaction) AS TotalRevenuePerItem
    FROM dbo.StoreTransactions t
    GROUP BY t.ItemID
    ORDER BY TotalRevenuePerItem DESC   -- order is required for the evaluator to be able to know which rows from pages to take
    OFFSET @pageSize * (@pageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
END;
```

You could also use an additional parameter in the stored procedure which accepts the name of the attribute you would like to group by and then you'd have two options of using it:

- make `IF - ELSE` statements based on that parameter and do appropriate `SELECT`'s
- turn the written select into a `nvarchar(max)` and then dynamically insert what to select and group by instead of *ItemID* from my example; at the end you'd simply execute that dynamic query using [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

**NOTE:** make sure not to forget to make covering indexes for other columns like I made the example for *ItemID*.

Comment: hey MK_ thanks for the reply ! :) 

This works like a charm, however... The data that I display which is grouped by date I need to show it all at once,,, so I'm guessing that my only solution here is to group it and insert somewhere, so that I don't have to pull it all at once ?

Comment: @User987 - Could you elaborate it further? I don't understand entirely... you mean, when you want to show the data by date (TransactionDate?), you need to show it grouped by ItemID, as well as CountryName, etc. - all at once?

Comment: So basically when I group by the data by transaction date I need to pull it all at once then... No paging no anything... Just raw representation from what I have in the table grouped by date to show in a graph... I figured the best way to do that is to just simply store it in a table which would contain this grouped data?

Comment: So when you want to group it by transaction date, you just pull everything... I don't think there's a more efficient way of doing that then simply selecting it like above - without the pagination part. Why is this use case bothering you, is it because you have a lot of data and pulling everything takes too much time?

Comment: Yes and taking up MSSQL resources all at once... Imagine pulling out 120000 records all at once and then grouping them by that, it's quite bad =/

Comment: Could you try adding the indexes as I suggested and then do the query? If it's not taking too much time after that, some strain on the hardware is worth having the live data if you ask me. If not and live data isn't so important then you could use some other table to store the data in and create an SQL Server Agent job which would refresh it at certain intervals. Just make sure that within that refresh procedure you calculate first in a temp table or such and only then, within a transaction, delete old and insert newly calculated data.

Comment: I'll try first with indexes and see what happens :D If it takes too much time like that, then I'll resort to adding extra table